# How to Accress Route in another namespace?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a namespace like foo/bar
I have added this line:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

but still getting this error
*

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with
>   message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::current()"

*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, newbie mistake, first of all if you put the line

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

you won't be able to call your methods, you'll get the error: *Laravel Non-static method*
second of all to access method Route::currentRouteName(), the namespace is wrong and *Illuminate\Routing\Router* is the correct one,

at the end you should make use of the facade like so:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route
```

Happy Coding YA'LL